# Python Addin Toolbar only works once

Tags: arcgis-10.1, python-addin

I am writing Python Addins for ArcGIS. I call a Python Toolbox, the Addin tool only works once in ArcCatalog when picked. If you pick it again nothing happens.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import os

 class OreconDBtoArcGISTool(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.enabled = True
         self.checked = False

     def onClick(self):

        toolboxName = "OreconDB_Toolbox"
        toolName = "OreconDBtoArcGISTool"
        relPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        pyt = relPath + os.sep + toolboxName + ".pyt"
        pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(pyt, toolName)
```

If I close and restart ArcCatalog the tool will work one more time again. Any Ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the Python Window giving you any hints? And if not, try adding a few print statement in the `onClick` to see if it's doing anything when you click it again.

Comment: I added a print under onClick and it only printed the first time picked and never again.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Addin so it was a Button instead of a Tool in the Python Addin Wizard and now it works as expected. ie I can run the pyt over and over again. I believe it is the behavior of "Tool" to be more interactive?

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import os

 class BlastHoleAttributestoOreConDBButton(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

     def onClick(self):
         toolboxName = "OreconDB_Toolbox"
         toolName = "OreconDBtoArcGISTool"
         relPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
         pyt = relPath + os.sep + toolboxName + ".pyt"
         pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(pyt, toolName)
```

Same code just being called as a button.

Comment: Well that makes sense. A Tool's onClick method probably only runs when it becomes the active tool, and not when you click on it if it's already the active tool. And yes Tools are meant to let you interact with the map using the mouse, not perform an action each time you click it, like a Button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try deleting out your im memory variables after execution?

```
del toolboxName, toolName, relPath, pyt
```

Are you closing the tool dialogue box after you run the addin and before you run it again? I guess it would be redundant for the program to run if the tool was already open?

Comment: thanks, tried that but still tool inactive after first pick.